# Save a result set containing repeated field to a destination table

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like to save the result set of the following query to a table.

```
SELECT

g, NEST(x) AS a

FROM 

(SELECT 1 AS g, 10 AS x), (SELECT 1 AS g, 20 AS x), (SELECT 1 AS g, 30 AS x), 
(SELECT 2 AS g, 100 AS x), (SELECT 2 AS g, 200 AS x)  

GROUP BY g
```

I use the web query composer with the options "Write if empty", "Allow Large Results: yes", "**Flatten Results: no**" and "Query priority: Interactive". I don't want to flatten query results.

**Query failes**: "**Error**: Unexpected. Please try again."

When I created a table with the following schema and selected the option "Append to table", I received the same error.

```
{
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "g",
            "type": "integer"
        },
        {
            "name": "a",
            "type": "integer",
            "mode": "repeated"
        }
    ]
}
```

Thank you for any advice.

Comment: I was just looking into this right now. Even added to paid enterprise support as a case, but received no answer yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue with the `NEST` function and `flattenResults` set to false: the two aren't compatible with each other at present.  We'd like to fix this but I don't have an ETA as the underlying issue is nontrivial.

If you have an existing table with a repeated field, you should be able to successfully `SELECT` it and output it as a repeated field using `flattenResults` set to false.

Comment: We'd love to transform a table which has `RECORD` type columns into another table. Something from `record1.timestamp` should be moved to `record2.timestamp` (and we no longer need `record1.timestamp`) How to proceed with this kind of query/destinationTable?

Comment: I don't think changing the name of a record or the parent record for a field using unflattened results is currently supported.  We do have longer-term plans for launching support for this type of schema transformation in the future however.

Comment: @DannyKitt I completely understand the first paragraph of your answer. I am not sure with the seconds paragraph. Is there currently a way to transform table containing two rows `{"p": 1, "a": 10}`, `{"p": 1, "a": 20}` to a table with repeated field containing one row `{"p": 1, "a": [10, 20]}`?

Comment: @Nathan Given that `NEST` does not work, I don't think there is a way to do that for an integer field.  But here's a workaround for strings:  
`select a, SPLIT(GROUP_CONCAT(b), ',')
from (select 'z' as a, 'y' as b), (select 'z' as a, 'x' as b)
group by a;`

Comment: @DannyKitt suppose that we want to have these now, and we already run a production app, what are our options?

Comment: @Pentium10 Until the features Danny alluded to are available, you will likely need to use some form of export/transform/import to update your existing table(s).  We also can't provide guidance at this time on when the new functionality will be released.