# Internal error on NEST when not flattening results

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to GROUP and return a repeated field into a new table

```
SELECT url, NEST(label) AS labels
FROM [mytable]
GROUP EACH BY url
```

It works when I've got the "Flatten Results" checkbox checked. When I uncheck that box I get 'Error: An internal error occurred and the request could not be completed.'

ontology-knowledge-graph:job_qD7a2Wrq9uCTqZrMbvwdy3v9Vtg

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NEST` is unfortunately incompatible with unflattened results, as also mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26933136/save-a-result-set-containing-repeated-field-to-a-destination-table/26937069#26937069).

A workaround that might work for you is using `SPLIT(GROUP_CONCAT(label))` instead of using `NEST`.  That should work if your label field is of type string.  You may need to choose an explicit separator for `GROUP_CONCAT` if your labels contain commas, but I think this solution should be workable.

Answer (score 3):

Recently found workaround for this issue:

Try

```
SELECT url, labels 
FROM (
  SELECT url, NEST(label) AS labels
  FROM [mytable]
  GROUP EACH BY url
) as a
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 1) as b
```

Note, you have to write result to table with `Allow Large Results` on and `Flatten Results` off

Answer (score 1):

From "[Query Reference](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference)" on NEST() :

BigQuery automatically flattens query results, so if you use the NEST function on the top level query, the results won't contain repeated fields. Use the NEST function when using a subselect that produces intermediate results for immediate use by the same query.

So if you want a non-flattened result here, you'd need to do a select * from your other select I'd think