# BigQuery NEST() returns 'Error: An internal error occurred'

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm trying to nest a field in the BigQuery UI (not the API) and continually get hit with an error when trying to output to a table without flattening:

> **Error:** An internal error occurred and the request could not be completed.

I'm using the [NEST()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#nest) function and I've tried this on the public Shakespeare dataset and continue to get the same error.

```
SELECT corpus, NEST(word) FROM [publicdata:samples.shakespeare] GROUP BY 1
```

My Job ID is: realself-main:bquijob_1bfb8310_153583ecbc2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There were tons of question on SO related to how to generate repeated fileds/records in BigQuery 
And, there were many different answers - ranging

from: NEST is not compatible with unflatten result - as in
[Internal error on NEST when not flattening results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31687051/internal-error-on-nest-when-not-flattening-results)

to: some solutions to address this issue using JS UDF  as in
 [Nest multiple repeated fields in BigQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35781272/nest-multiple-repeated-fields-in-bigquery/35782601#35782601) ;
[Create a table with Record type column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35040039/create-a-table-with-record-type-column/35043714#35043714) ;
[create a table with a column type RECORD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34996384/create-a-table-with-a-column-type-record/35000299#35000299)

there are more  - you can search

> But surprisingly enough - recently, I found how to make NEST() work almost as it supposed to work!

Try below to see the trick

```
SELECT corpus, words 
FROM (
  SELECT corpus, NEST(word) AS words
  FROM [publicdata:samples.shakespeare] 
  GROUP BY 1
) AS a
CROSS JOIN (SELECT 1) AS b
```

Note, you have to write result to table with `Allow Large Results` on and `Flatten Results` off

Comment: The trick worked great! I've used the cross join a few other times to trick BQ, didn't think of trying it here..

Comment: i found this after quite heavy experimentation with nest() as it is one of the  weakest yet demanded feature