# collect_set for Google bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery

Hi I was not able to find this anywhere.

How do I do a collect_set in Google BigQuery?

I have a query already written in Big query

select 
user_id,
steps,
from table

I need to put all of the steps for each user_id into an array like collect_set would.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try using [NEST()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#nest) function:

```
SELECT user_id, NEST(steps) AS steps 
FROM table
GROUP BY user_id
```

See below for some tricks on how to make NEST work to be able to write to table
[BigQuery NEST() returns 'Error: An internal error occurred'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35878957/bigquery-nest-returns-error-an-internal-error-occurred/35883289#35883289)

Another option would be to just build list of steps as string using [GROUP_CONCAT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#group_concat):

```
SELECT user_id, GROUP_CONCAT(steps) AS steps 
FROM table
GROUP BY user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent for `group_concat` in BigQuery Standard SQL is `string_agg`. So, the equivalent query could be written as:

```
select user_id, string_agg(steps) as steps
from table 
group by user_id
```

Refer the docs here - https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aggregate_functions#string_agg

Answer (score 0):

You may get the result you want with `ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT )`, for instance

```
SELECT 
    ARRAY_AGG(DISTINCT value)
FROM 
    UNNEST([1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 5]) AS value
```

gives you an array with `[1, 2, 3, 5]`